# Can anyone tell me what anime this nekomimi girl is from?

Tags: tayutama

[image]

Does anyone know who the girl with the cat ears is or what anime she is from?
The one between Shana and Naruto.

Thanks

Comment: Man this picture brings back memories.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is this picture from? How do I use Reverse Image Search to find the source of an anime/manga image?](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21618/where-is-this-picture-from-how-do-i-use-reverse-image-search-to-find-the-source)

Answer (score 10):

This is the character Mito Mashiro, the main heroine from the visual novel/eroge [Tayutama: Kiss on my Deity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tayutama:_Kiss_on_my_Deity) by studio Lump of Sugar. It has a 2009 anime adaptation, but I think the image posted is taken from the VN directly. She is the incarnation of a goddess, and her goal is to bring harmony between humans and a fictional supernatural race called Tayutai. She also falls in love with the protagonist.

Here's a similar picture from the visual novel. It's a slightly different pose, but I think it's clear that it's still her.

[image: Mito Mashiro]

Answer (score 5):

After some image cropping and Google reverse image search, I almost instantly found her to be [Mashiro Mito](http://myanimelist.net/character.php?id=18191) from the [**Tayutama: Kiss on my Deity**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tayutama:_Kiss_on_my_Deity) series

[image]